# Is there a gem to make Git and Rails work together for more robust migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, rails-migrations

I've heard before that Rails migrations are flawed, but I never really experienced any example of this firsthand until just recently. What I now realize is that if a migration relies on a particular state of the *code*, then you're in trouble if you try to clone the repo two years later and run all the migrations (as a lot of them will depend on older versions of the code).

I thought this guy had a good idea:

http://www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2011/02/28/rails-model-safe-migrations/

Is there anything like this: a gem (say) to automatically check out the commit where each migration was added, all the way up to HEAD?

Obviously it wouldn't be a fool-proof system, as it does rely on every migration being legitimately possible from a clean slate at the point it was committed to the repo (I can imagine cases where teams have written migrations that only *incidentally* work based on things they've done with the database completely outside of version control). But it would certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: Just wondering, have you considered just a `rake db:schema:load`?

Comment: What Benjamin Tan said. First ensure you have an up-to-date definition of the schema in db/schema.rb with `rake db:schema:dump`
and then use `rake db:schema:load` to create all the tables without running through the migrations.

Comment: @BenjaminTan: Thanks for that. I guess I was stuck on this notion that I really wanted it to be possible to make migrations work purely as deltas (after all, that's how Git works, right?); but you're right that the sensible thing really is to just use `db:schema:load`.

Comment: Glad that help you out. I guess you should only rely on migrations in short steps during development. I usually delete migrations after I'm sure I don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 cases that could happen, and in each case, the solution is different:

1. You develop the code and deliver it in small release increments. The solution is running somewhere, has data in it, and you have to migrate it every time you deliver a new version.

   ==> Rails is then a perfect answer how to develop and deliver the new releases. I do that all the time (with 2 applications where I am the only user), and never had a problem.
2. You develop the code, and deliver a lot of small releases (with the first approach). You then want to instantiate it on a new server, without any data stored there.

   ==> Then dumping your scheme and loading it on the new server is the best way, just to ensure that everything is in place.

I do not know Capistrano, perhaps there are options to do it differently. So if you have something like the scenario 1, use the Rails approach, in case of scenario 2, use the dump-and-load approach.

Answer (score 1):

Great reason to version your database schema.rb.

The git changelog will show when the schema.rb changed, and give you the commit hash.